# AWS Server SMTP Email connection timeout n Swiftmailer

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, smtp

Recently moved PHP project on AWS.
I have used Swift-mailer to send Email using SMTP.

I have got Sometime error and sometime email is working.
Error is

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Connection to
>   smtp.example.com:587 Timed Out"

Code:

```
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.example.com', 587))
  ->setUsername('info@example.com')
  ->setPassword('********');
```

I have search lots of but i can not get exact solution and no hint.
So please help.

I have now using PHPmailer.There is displaying sometime email is sent and some time getting following error.
There is displaying error:

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 Authentication succeeded "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "235 Authentication succeeded "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 OK "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Accepted "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 Accepted "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Accepted
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: DATA not accepted from server:
```

Thank You.

Comment: First of all, it's not related to Swift Mailer. It's about the network connection between your web server & SMTP server. Is the network status of your SMTP server stable enough?

Comment: Yes I have already chat with domain email provider. He is asking that our email settings is good.

Comment: And sometime email is working good. Is there some settings need to done on AWS side?

Comment: If the settings in AWS haven't changed recently, the cause shouldn't be on AWS settings. To prove the connection is stable or not, you can try `nc -vz smtp.example.com 587` every minute (or other time intervals you like) if you're using Linux. (Hint: use cron job & redirect the output to a text file)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have using Ubuntu. I have run your command its displaying **Success** message.
Please check Updated Question

Comment: You should send the log to the SMTP admin for their diagnosis. Maybe they're blocking some keywords / recipient